# error reading files while looping through files in a directory in python2.7

Tags: python, file, file-io, python-2.7, tuples

I've been googling this problem since yesterday and to no avail;

When I loop through a number of files in one directory, and process the rows of each file within that loop, I always close, but it seems as though python is opening all the files in the same memory space, so when I loop through a file I retrieve all the records from the previously opened files, it's as if they're in a pointer array. . . .wtf?

```
    import os
    import sys
    import glob
    import string
    import cPickle
    path2 = './'
    columnShuffleTable = loadColumnTable('myTable') #func previously defined
    codeScrambleTable = loadScrambleTable('theirTable') #func previously defined
    pathToFiles2 = glob.glob(os.path.join(path2, '*.DAT'))

    for curFile in pathToFiles2:    
        _list = ['',] 
        #this is the variable with which I'm having a problem
        unscrambledCodes = file(curFile[-10:], 'r') 
        #this always yields the actual first line of the file at which I am currently at
        line = unscrambledCodes.readline() 
        _list[0] = '|' + line.strip() #stripping trailing spaces
        #the list length at this point always equates to '1', so up to here everything is great
        print "list length:", len(_list) 
        # this always reads the 2nd line of the very first file I loaded. . .wtf?
        line = unscrambledCodes.readline().strip() 

        while(line):
            #for unscrambledCodes [my input file] 
            print "len list: ", len(_list), "infile", unscrambledCodes 
            nextLine = unscrambledCodes.readline().strip()

            if not nextLine:
                _list.append('|' + line)
                break
            else:
                _list.append( '|' + line[:-14] + scrambleCode(line[-12:], columnShuffleTable, codeScrambleTable))
            #end if

            line = nextLine
        unscrambledCodes.close()
        outfile = open(curFile[-10:-4] + '.Scrambled', 'w')
        output = '\n'.join(_list)
        outfile.write(output)
        outfile.close()
```

as requested, here are my i/o samples:

input file1:
AB00007737106517           COSTCLASSU275
C000000010031932155750539976333693187714
C000000010031932155750539976105307608239

file2:
AB00007736638744           COSTCLASSU275
C000000010030284907699012480608351468369
C000000020030284907699012480751885101503

file3:
AB00007737148207           COSTCLASSU275
C000000010032271716759259098738354718484
C000000020032271716759259098394986919513

desired output file1:
AB00007737148207            COSTCLASSU275
|C000000010031932155750539976079292077121
|C000000010031932155750539976126217711213

file2:
AB00007736638744            COSTCLASSU275
|C000000010030284907699012480968864628712
|C000000020030284907699012480294550195814

file3:
AB00007737106517            COSTCLASSU275
|C000000010032271716759259098216262704445
|C000000020032271716759259098085462231948

current output file1:
AB00007737148207            COSTCLASSU275
|C000000010031932155750539976079292077121
|C000000010031932155750539976126217711213

file2:
AB00007736638744            COSTCLASSU275
|C000000010031932155750539976079292077121
|C000000010031932155750539976126217711213
.
.
.
|C000000010030284907699012480968864628712
|C000000020030284907699012480294550195814
file3:
AB00007737106517            COSTCLASSU275
|C000000010031932155750539976079292077121
|C000000010031932155750539976126217711213
.
.
.
|C000000010030284907699012480968864628712
|C000000020030284907699012480294550195814
.
.
.
|C000000010032271716759259098216262704445
|C000000020032271716759259098085462231948

Comment: This seems like the kind of thing which **with statements** were designed for. I.e. Grab a list of all the filenames, and open each one inside a with statement...

Comment: As written I don't see why unscrambledCodes wouldn't do the right thing for the second `readline()`.  Perhaps showing some of the actual output, and what you expected would help clarify what the actual problem is?

Comment: @jszakmeister you have no idea how I want to do that, but the data is so sensitive I'd get fired :-(, probably get sent to court also

Comment: @pyruva you could try and make an example you could share (three files with foo's and bar's with numbers). I really doubt that the problem is where you see it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the unscrambledCodes.readline() will read one line of the file at a time, incrementing to the next row until the whole file is read in.

You can use something like:

```
content = unscrambledCodes.readlines()
```

Which will read each line into an array.  Then you can iterate through the content, and update the lines as you wish.

Also, instead of file(), I generally use

```
myFile = open('filename.txt','r')
content = myFile.readlines()
myFile.close()
```

Comment: I only changed that to file() this morning, they're both failing, as well as your solution, sorry

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the issue correctly.  Is it when you set `output = '\n'.join(_list)` that _list includes items from previous iterations?

Comment: Hi Sam, no, as soon as i went int the while loop, previous records started coming out of the line var

Answer (score 0):

the general consensus is to use open instead of file. I'd start with that.

Second, try to do a generator comprehension on your opened file as it is much easier (the next method will return a newline) as `new_file=[x.strip() for x in unscrambledCodes)]` , then do whatever other operations you have to , like `new_file=["|"+line for line in new_file[:-1]]` and `new_file[-1]=......`

Also as someone else above pointed out , you might wanna try the with keyword (even though it will bring another level of indentation) like

`with open("....","r") as in_file, open("...","w") as out_file:`

```
`'''.... do your stuff'''`
```

Comment: changed to file this morning to see if that might change anything. . .it isn't

Comment: thanks for the with thing, I think I tried it last night but to no avail. . .no harm in trying it again though. I'll tell you what happens